# Method for solving distributional ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $u$ be a distribution on the real line. I know that the equation $x(u-u')= \delta_0 -\delta_2$ ($\delta_a$ is the dirac delta at the point $a$) can be solved by putting  $u-u'=v$ and then solving $xv=\delta_0$ and $xv=-\delta_2$. However I dont understand why this works. If somebody could explain to me whats going on here Id be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1$ satisfy $xv_1=\delta_0$ and $v_2$ satisfy $xv_2=\delta_2$. Then
$x(v_1-v_2) = xv_1-xv_2 = \delta_0-\delta_2.$

Comment: Oh thanks! And then one solves  $u-u'= v_1 -v_2$ as an inhomogeneous first order equation in the usual way? By the way do you know why $xv_1=\delta_0$ gives that $v_1$ is a linear combination of delta derivatives?

Comment: To solve $u - u' = v_1 - v_2$ i recommend to start by multiplication with $e^{-x}$ so that the left hand side becomes $(e^{-x} u)'$.

Comment: $xv_1 = \delta_0$ has particular solution $v_1 = -\delta_0'$ and homogeneous solution $v_1 = C \delta_0$. Thus the general solution is $v_1 = -\delta_0' + C \delta_0$.

Comment: Thank you! I just have one more question: how do you get that $xv_1=\delta_0$ implies that $v_1=-\delta_0'$? I mean I see that this is the case but I don't see how you arrive there. Is it just by trying?

Comment: Actually I had myself problems finding what is here called $v_1$ when someone else had posted a similar problem a while ago. Later I realized that $x \delta_0' = -\delta_0$. I don't know of any way to find the solution directly from the equation.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway!